# SVG not showing in Opera and Firefox, but Chrome

Tags: svg, cross-browser

I'm trying to display this simple embedded SVG image:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="125" x="141" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">test</text>
 </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome shows it, but Opera and Firefox don't. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is supported, in fact :) You have two options - old one, using XHTML, and new one, using HTML5 and a modern browser with an HTML5 parser:

XHTML example (works in most browsers, including old Internet Explorer with the Adobe plugin installed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <title>SVG embedded inline in XHTML</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>SVG embedded inline in XHTML</h1>

    <object id="AdobeSVG" classid="clsid:78156a80-c6a1-4bbf-8e6a-3cd390eeb4e2"> </object>
    <?import namespace="svg" urn="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" implementation="#AdobeSVG"?>

    <svg:svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300px" height="200px">
      <svg:circle cx="150px" cy="100px" r="50px" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5px"/>
    </svg:svg>

  </body>

</html>
```

html5 example(atm supported by IE9, FF4 and Chrome, Safari in near future):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG in text/html</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>SVG in text/html</h1>
    <p><svg height=86 width=90 viewBox='5 9 90 86' style='float: left;'>
      <path stroke=#F53F0C stroke-width=10 fill=#F5C60C stroke-linejoin=round d='M 10,90 L 90,90 L 50,14 Z'/>
      <line stroke=black stroke-width=10 stroke-linecap=round x1=50 x2=50 y1=45 y2=75 />
    </svg><b>Warning:</b> Remember that &PlusMinus; means that there are two
    solutions!</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if SVG is in file, not embedded, what is the syntax in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You need an HTML5 parser for that to get that properly displayed, e.g. Firefox 4, or [Opera 11.50](http://labs.opera.com/news/2011/02/22/). Check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/svg-html5) for more browser details.

You can use XHTML with inline SVG images and it will work in all SVG-capable browsers though. See [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/inline.xhtml) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this site, you do have some options](http://jong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL_v15/html/Web-Use.html). Although I personally struggle with this, as well...

> "A simple and easy way to include SVG
> into a web page is to use the XHTML
> object tag. Here is an example:"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <title>SVG Included with <object> tag in an XHTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>  <h1>An SVG rectangle (via <object> tag)</h1>

  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="web_square.svg">
    Browser does not support SVG files!
  </object>
</body>
</html>
```

> "Inclusion of SVG file. The "image/svg+xml" is the MIME type of the included file. It must be given."

> "Text that will be displayed if a browser does not support SVG. Browsers should ignore tags that they don't understand thereby exposing the text."

He also outlines a method "Using Name Spaces"...

"Through Name Spaces, an SVG file can be placed directly in an XHTML file. Here is an example of a very simple XHTML file that displays a blue square. The square was drawn with Inkscape. (For clarity, the Inkscape drawing was saved as a plain SVG file and some of the unused rectangle attributes were deleted.)"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> <title>SVG Embedded into an XHTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body> <h1>An SVG rectangle (via Name spaces)</h1>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0"
   width="150"
   height="150"
   id="svg1341">
  <defs   id="defs1343" />
  <g      id="layer1">
    <rect
          width="90"   height="90"
          x="30"       y="30"
          style="fill:#0000ff;
          fill-opacity:0.75;
          stroke:#000000    stroke-width:1px"
          id="rect1353" />
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck... being SVG isn't easy...

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found the reason: directly embedding SVG tags in HTML is not supported yet in most browsers.